# what are the activities, broadcasts etc,, present in my apk, in a simple readable format?

Tags: android

I have an android apk. I want to know how many activities, broadcasts etc.. present in that raw apk. Is it possible?

I tried using apk analyzer in android studio, but again i need to search in  manifest and need to have a look up. is there any easy way to figure out, so that after giving the apk, it should display the component names.
is there any such tool available?

Comment: use solid explorer file manager

Comment: @DivyeshPatel seems to be solid explorer is a simple explorer apk, which used to see the contents in sd card, internal storage.. am i right? But my query is different. how to know the components in a raw apk?

Comment: it shows apk structures and other info about app

Comment: @DivyeshPatel No. my question was different.

Comment: check this: https://ibb.co/g67FMG

Comment: @DivyeshPatel yeah. looks pretty good. Thank you. Is there any windows tool available similar way?

Comment: don't know about windows tool, but that app do more than that. just buy it from playstore

Answer (score 0):

@DivyeshPatel Thank you. I tried solid Explorer.

Below steps can help...
Install Solid Explorer -> browse your apk -> click on options -> select AppViewer

It will display the components present in your apk.
Thank you.